# Check which cells (that hold lists) contains a certain value?

Tags: r, list

In R I would like to search each cell in a column, with the column containing a series of lists. I would like to return the index (or return T/F) for the cells that contain a certain value.

For example - I created this test dataframe.

```
test <- data.frame(rows = 1:5, values = 0)
test$values <- list(1, c(2,3), c(4:6), 4, 0)
```

Attempting to query it using:

```
test[4 %in% test$values,]
```

In this example I would like to return the cells that contain the value 4 (so row 3 and 4 should be true). How do I do this? My current query returns just one TRUE as it is just testing the entire column (not each cell in that column).

I have in the past solved this using a for loop (roughly as below). eg:

```
test$result <- FALSE
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
    if (4 %in% test$values[i]){
        test$result[i] <- TRUE
    }
}
```

I don't really want this to be my solution each time I need to query like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` functions in the `purrr` package are good for working with nested data like this:

```
purrr::map_lgl(test$values, ~ 4 %in% .)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you. This is the type of solution I am after. Using the map_lgl() function give s me the type of workflow I am after for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a list you need to loop over it using `sapply`/`lapply`

```
test$result <- sapply(test$values, function(x) 4 %in% x)

test
#  rows  values result
#1    1       1  FALSE
#2    2    2, 3  FALSE
#3    3 4, 5, 6   TRUE
#4    4       4   TRUE
#5    5       0  FALSE
```

If you want to subset those rows you could do

```
test[sapply(test$values, function(x) 4 %in% x), ]

#  rows  values
#3    3 4, 5, 6
#4    4       4
```

Comment: Ok so there is no way to solve this without creating a seperate column to hold the results of the query?

Comment: Well you don't have to store the logical vector in your dataframe, you can just store it as an independent vector and use it when needed (although you have to make sure it doesn't get out of sync when the dataframe changes).

Comment: @ElleniToumpas If you want to subset those rows you don't need to create a separate column for that.  I updated the answer reflecting that.

Comment: Oh yes that solution makes sense too. Thank you! Still learning all the ways to run queries in R. This is also a great solution. Thank you Ronak.